# Python program not returning function after if statement

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a Python Tic-Tac-Toe bot and it keeps stopping after one `if` statement instead of restarting the function (code below). I'm fairly beginner-level at Python and would appreciate simpler answers.

code:

```
def process():
    uin = input('enter a move...')
    if uin == 'A1':
        atwo.remove('A1')
        bone.remove('A1')
        btwo.remove('A1')
        sou = random.choice(aone)
        print(sou)
        aone.remove(sou)
        return process
    elif uin == 'A2':
        aone.remove('A2')
        athree.remove('A2')
        btwo.remove('A2')
        sou = random.choice(atwo)
        print(sou)
        atwo.remove(sou)
        return process
    elif uin == 'A3':
        atwo.remove('A3')
        btwo.remove('A3')
        bthree.remove('A3')
        sou = random.choice(athree)
        print(sou)
        athree.remove(sou)
        return process
    elif uin == 'B1':
        aone.remove('B1')
        btwo.remove('B1')
        cone.remove('B1')
        sou = random.choice(bone)
        print(sou)
        bone.remove(sou)
        return process
    elif uin == 'B2':
        aone.remove('B2')
        atwo.remove('B2')
        athree.remove('B2')
        bone.remove('B2')
        bthree.remove('B2')
        cone.remove('B2')
        ctwo.remove('B2')
        cthree.remove('B2')
        sou = random.choice(btwo)
        print(sou)
        btwo.remove(sou)
        return process
    elif uin == 'B3':
        athree.remove('B2')
        btwo.remove('B2')
        cthree.remove('B2')
        sou = random.choice(bthree)
        print(sou)
        bthree.remove(sou)
        return process
    elif uin == 'C1':
        bone.remove('C1')
        btwo.remove('C1')
        ctwo.remove('C1')
        sou = random.choice(cone)
        print(sou)
        bthree.remove(sou)
        return process
    elif uin == 'C2':
        btwo.remove('C2')
        cone.remove('C2')
        cthree.remove('C2')
        sou = random.choice(ctwo)
        ctwo.remove(sou)
        return process
    elif uin == 'C3':
        btwo.remove('C3')
        btwo.remove('C3')
        ctwo.remove('C3')
        sou = random.choice(cthree)
        print(sou)
        cthree.remove(sou)
        return process 
process()
```

Comment: does this game play w/o playerinteraction?

Comment: `process` is the function by itself, returning just the function won't *execute* it. So replace all your `return process` with `return process()` and you should solve the "my function stops after 1 iteration" problem.
This however doesn't mean your code is bug free, but this one in particular will disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to understand the difference between `return process` and `return process()`:

`return process` will not execute anything, it will just exit the function with the result being a reference to the process function. Your last line could use it like `result = process()` You could then loop on that result and you could exit the application at the end of the game by just returning None instead of the function.

`return process()` would execute the process() function and return its own result. You would get into the function more than once but it means that it will start chaining calls to functions and will chain-exit all of them at the end of the game. For a tic-tac-toe, it should work but for more complex stuff, this would probably cause a stack overflow.

The correct way would be to have a loop on the call to process() and not bother returning process itself.

Answer (score 0):

Put the function in a while loop

```
while True:
    process()
```

Then inside your function when the conditions to win the game are achived, put a break so it ends the loop.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in your code, you are tending 3 different lists of "where are open spots".  I think it wouldbe easier to just tend one list instead, and get the "open" spots before choosing where to place.

You are trying to call the same function out of itself - this will lead to lots of stack-frames for each function call (python isolates function calls by preparing a "variable stack" memory area for that funciton that is cleaned up after you leave the function. If your function calls itself recursivly - they accumulate and clog down your computers memory) - most of the time it is better to avoid that and code non-recursivly using loops.

A board naturally leads to a 2-dim lists, you choose to also adress it by a letter and 1-indexed which leads to some back-and-forth calculations between the indexes in the list and the "output".

I added some functions that do certain things (return all unused spaces, set a space, pretty print the board, check wins):

```
ordA = ord("A")  # get the ascii value of A so we can compute the letter by the list-index

def getFieldsNotUsed(f):
    """Return all possible fields that are empty (if .strip()ed)"""
    for r_idx,row in enumerate(field):
        for c_idx,col in enumerate(row):
            if col.strip() == "":
                # get the letter that belongs to "A" + the 0bases list index
                yield chr(ordA+r_idx)+str(c_idx+1)

def setField(player,coord,f):
    """Places player (X or O) at coord [A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3,C1,C2,C3]-string"""
    print(f"{player} sets at {coord}:\n")
    r_idx = ord(coord[0])-ordA # compute the list index for row 
    c_idx = int(coord[1])-1    # colum is easier, just int-ify the string and subtract 1
    f[r_idx][c_idx]=player

def printField(f):
    """Pretty prints the field given by f"""
    middle = 2
    for r in f:
        print("\t " + " | ".join( r ))
        if middle: # 0 is False
            print("\t" + "---|---|---")
            middle -= 1
    print("\n")

def checkWin(f):
    """Retunrs a winner-string or None - checks all rows && columns && both diagonals"""
    # check rows
    for r in f:
        if all( v == r[0] and v.strip() for v in r):
            return f"{r[0]} won!"
    # check cols
    for c in zip(*f):
        if all( v == c[0] and v.strip() for v in c):
            return f"{r[0]} won!"
    # check diag
    if (f[0][0] == f[1][1] == f[2][2] or 
        f[0][2] == f[1][1] == f[2][0]) and f[1][1].strip() :
        return f"{r[0]} won!"

    return None # no wins
```

Main program

```
import random

# prepare the empty field with spaces - it is the only list to tend to
field = [[" "," "," "],[" "," "," "],[" "," "," "]]
player = ""
# get all fields that are still open
open_fields = list(getFieldsNotUsed(field)) 

# loop while open fields are present
while open_fields:
    # toggle the player from "" (at start) to X, then from X to O and back
    player = "X" if player != "X" else "O"

    # choose randomly, set player, print field
    place_where = random.choice(open_fields)
    setField(player, place_where,field)
    printField(field)     

    # check win-conditions, continue loop if None else break
    win = checkWin(field)
    if win is None:
        open_fields = list(getFieldsNotUsed(field))
    else:
        # we got a winner - print it and exit loop
        print(win)
        break
else:
    print("Draw")
```

---

You can find the documentation to most of the used functions (`ord`,`chr`,`int`,`range`,`zip`) here:  [Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html)

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't be using `return` after every `if` - `elif` loop. Instead assign it to a variable and then increment that variable for every loop. Only one `return` per `def`:

```
def some_function(x, y):
    x = []
    y = "Some String"
    x.append(y)
    return y
```